String.from_java_bytes and encoding
I have a JRuby application, which gets invoked from a Java main program, and receives data in form of a Java byte Array (byte[]). As this data originates from a text file, I know that it is text in some encoding. To convert it to a Ruby String, I use
str = String.from_java_bytes(byte_array)

This works, but to my surprise, I find that when I ask for str.encoding, that the encoding is reported as UTF8. This is not a real problem, because I can always impose the correct encoding (which I happen to know) by str.force_encoding. My question is however:
How come that JRuby guesses the encoding to be UTF-8? I would have expected, that since JRuby has no information about the external data, it would set the encoding to ASCII_8BIT and leave it up to the programmer to set the correct encoding, respectively have the content converted to UTF8 (which would be necessary, when the external data is not in utf8).

Related: Jruby & UTF-8. Switch to UTF-8 Everywhere…

@JosefZ : Thank you very much for those links. Very enlighting reading, and indeed related to my question!
